# Custom validations for avatar not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I am trying to add some custom validations on my attached avatar on sign up.
I am using devise to manage users.

When I place a `binding.pry` in my `image_type` method, all the logic seems to be working fine, but when removed, I can add any size file and any type without an error being risen...

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
  validates :email, uniqueness: true
  validate :image_type
  has_one_attached :avatar

  private

  def image_type
    extn = avatar.content_type.downcase
    size = avatar.byte_size.to_f
    if ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"].include?(extn) != true
      errors.add(:image, "must be in format .png, .jpg or .jpeg only")
    elsif ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"].include?(extn) && size > 5.kilobytes.to_f
      errors.add(:image, "is too large - You cannot upload an image file greater than 5MB")
    end
  end
end
```

`sign_up form`

```
<%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :profile_picture %><br />
          <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "form-control"  %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: "form-control", placeholder: "name@email.com" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "first_name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "last_name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :password %>
          <% if @minimum_password_length %>
          <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
          <% end %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field mb-3">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Continue", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <br>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`_error_messages.html.erb`

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <h4>
      <%= I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
        count: resource.errors.count,
        resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
      %>
    </h4>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: add your controller code

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :avatar
    validates :avatar,
        content_type: [:gif, :png, :jpg, :jpeg],
        size: { less_than: 5.megabytes , message: 'is too large - You cannot upload an image file greater than 5MB' }
end
```